# Difficulty using import/export for two javascript files in same directory, not using react or node

Tags: javascript, import, export

I am following a simple online tutorial. Nothing fancy is going on and I am not using Node or React. The guy is using Sandbox but I am just using Brackets and a folder on my desktop to contain my files. Everything is fine until I have to export a class from one script (**paddle.js**) to the main script (**index.js**). Prior to changing the first lines, I just have a blank canvas in the browser, as expected. After changing the first lines (by inserting export/import commands, respectively) I get the following errors in Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier    index.js:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export    paddle.js:1

here is my script paddle.js:

```
export default class Paddle {
    constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight){

        this.width = 150;
        this.height = 30;

        this.position = {
            x: (gameWidth - this.width) / 2,
            y: gameHeight - this.height - 10,
        };
    }

    draw(ctx){
        ctx.fillRect(this.position.x,this.position.y,this.width,this.height);
    }
}
```

here is my script index.js:

```
import Paddle from 'paddle';

let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const GAME_WIDTH = 800;

const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

ctx.clearRect(0,0, GAME_WIDTH,GAME_HEIGHT) //clears region between corners of screen, necessary fro re-drawing because screen does not 'reset' until I tell it to.

let paddle = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
paddle.draw(ctx);
```

here is my html file, index.html (mostly boilerplate):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>

        #gameScreen{

            border: 1px solid black;

        }

    </style>

    <title>breakout tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id = "gameScreen" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

    <script src = "index.js"></script>
    <script src = "paddle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am supposed to get a blue paddle at the bottom of the screen, like in this guy's video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EMxBkqC4z0
[image]

**EDIT:** @Talgat Saribayev So I am trying to follow your advice and am running HTTP server from the console. I set the directory to the "/src" directory of the attached zip, which I have on my desktop. I am getting "404 not found" errors. I think this is an easy fix but I don't know what to do. Probably the import lines in the classes. Help?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xKGUpfmjHggY50lUyFrAKFqo_msPjZKS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Ok there is answer from hatinacat2000, but you can enable ES6 import export natively on Chrome. I will try to explain each step and configuration in order to run you code.

1. Add `type="module"` to your script tags

```
<script type="module" src = "index.js"></script>
<script type="module" src = "paddle.js"></script>
```

In order to enable `ES6 modules`. For more info: https://medium.com/dev-channel/es6-modules-in-chrome-canary-m60-ba588dfb8ab7

2. Load throw some server, or will face CORS issue. Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server
3. Also you need to update `import` in your code of **index.js**

```
import Paddle from './paddle.js';
```

That's it, now you can use `ES6 modules` natively.

**EDIT** Ther rest of the instructions specifically for hatinacat2000 case.

1. Unzip files into any directory, open terminal and move to *MyFiles*
2. Move you *asset* directory/folder into *src*.

```
$ tree ./src -L 1
./src
├── assets
├── ball.js
├── game.js
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── input.js
└── paddle.js
```

3. Change all imports in js files to relative. Don't forget **.js** extension. For example for *game.js*

```
import Paddle from "./paddle.js";
import InputHandler from "./input.js";
import Ball from "./ball.js";
```

4. Run your http-server. `$ http-server ./src` and open in browser http://localhost:8080/

That what I've got
[image]

Comment: I am still having trouble. I followed your advice and ran http server in the console. I set it up to make the default directory the "MyFiles" folder in the zipped folder I just appended to my original post. Can you please walk me through this (from your desktop) because I am getting 404 not-found errors for all classes. I typed "myipaddres:8080/src/index.html" into the URL

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, this guy is using an IDE that may be in the browser or through some fancy file management. He needs to use import/export. I don't need to do that because all of my scripts are in the same directory. So I took those import/export commands out. What I *DID* need to do was load the "Paddle" class into the HTML file ahead of the other .js file (index.js) that uses it (duh, I loaded them in reverse order). When I do, I get this:

[image]

Now, I understand that this solution is pretty common on stack overflow so I want to say how much I appreciate everyone who has the experience to read our chicken scratch and say "hmm, bet you forgot to 'x,y,z'!". As I continue to grow I will anticipate solutions to import/export command trouble being of this kind.